# Get average color of UIView within range

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, uicolor

I am building a `UIButton` that, when in a `UIScrollView` changes color to contrast the average color of the view behind it. In order to do this, I wrote the following functions:

```
extension UIView {

    func getPixelColor(from origin: CGPoint, with width: CGFloat, with height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        var x = origin.x
        var y = origin.y
        var vals: [CGFloat] = []

        while x < origin.x + width {
            while y < origin.y + height {
                let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: 4)
                let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
                let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

                context!.translateBy(x: x, y: y)
                layer.render(in: context!)
                let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(pixel[0])/255.0,
                                    green: CGFloat(pixel[1])/255.0,
                                    blue: CGFloat(pixel[2])/255.0,
                                    alpha: CGFloat(pixel[3])/255.0)
                pixel.deallocate()
                vals.append(color.avg)
                y += 1
            }
            x += 1
        }

        let sumArray = vals.reduce(0, +)
        let avgArrayValue = CGFloat(sumArray) / CGFloat(vals.count)
        return avgArrayValue
    }

}
```

Issue here is that I want to get an average color in a certain range, but right now this function runs too slowly to be executed everytime the `UIScrollView` moves. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this function / issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you re-allocate `pixel`, `colorSpace` and `bitmapInfo` in every iteration - maybe move these outside of the loop? Also, did you use Instruments to see which lines are the bottleneck?

Comment: That code is horrendously inefficient. You need to create your pixel, colorspace, bitmapInfo, and context objects outside the loop and reuse them. That will make a huge difference in performance. (You'd still translate your context to shift one pixel at a time into position). That's still somewhat inefficient, but it would be way, waaaaay faster than what you're doing now.

Comment: And what is the code for `color.avg` ?